# How to detect a buffer underflow with WASAPI?

Tags: c, winapi, audio, wasapi

Using the [Windows Audio Session API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455(v=vs.85).aspx), how does one detect a buffer underflow, also known as buffer underrun?

Comment: The only thing i can think of is checking for AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_DATA_DISCONTINUITY. Only works for capture clients though, there doesnt seem to be an equivalent for render clients.